# Cannot start Outlook 2013 normally

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

When starting my Outlook 2013 application, I got the below error.

How can I get rid of it and get my Outlook back to work?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outlook 2007 - Cannot start Outlook - Cannot open the Outlook window](http://superuser.com/questions/150628/outlook-2007-cannot-start-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window), [Error when starting Outlook 2007 on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/41758/error-when-starting-outlook-2007-on-windows-7)

Comment: It seems reasonable that different problems happen with outlook 2007 and 2013.

Answer (score 1):

That error means one of the following things:

- You have the wrong mailbox name specified in your profile or you don't have permissions to it.
- Your profile has additional mailboxes listed that either don't exist or you don't have permission to them.
- You are mapped to a PST file that is either corrupt or missing, and your mail is set to deliver to that location.
- You are subscribed to a SharePoint list that no longer exists or you no longer have access to.
- Your profile is mapped to an external web-based mail service (e.g. Hotmail, Gmail, Yahoo Mail, etc.) and the password has changed on that account.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile probably became corrupted.

> Open Control Panel.  For Windows Vista, or Windows 7, click the Start
>   button, click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click User
>   Accounts.  For Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, type Control Panel while on
>   the Start screen.
>
> Click the Mail icon.
>
> Click Show Profiles.
>
> Click Add.
>
> In the Profile Name box, type a new name for the profile.
>
> Specify the user name, the primary SMPT address, and the password, and
>   then click Next.
>
> You may receive this prompt: Allow this website to configure
>   alias@domain server settings?
>
> In this prompt, click to select the Don’t ask me about this again
>   checkbox, and then click Allow.
>
> In the Add Account dialog, click Finish.
>
> Under Always use this profile, select the profile name that you used
>   in step 5.
>
> Click OK.

[source](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/I-can-t-start-Microsoft-Outlook-2010-or-2013-or-receive-the-error-%E2%80%9CCannot-start-Microsoft-Office-Outlook-Cannot-open-the-Outlook-Window%E2%80%9D-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)